# es posible dar acceso a PHPMyadmin en cPanel a otro usuario para una base de datos determinada?

Tags: phpmyadmin, hosting, cpanel

Buen dia, tengo un web hosting de hostgator contratado en el cual me dan una cuenta de cpanel comun y corriente, allí tengo mas de 20 bases de datos y quisiera saber si es posible dar acceso a una de ellas a un amigo sin que vea las otras 19? ya que si le doy mi clave principal de cPanel verá absolutamente todo, en cuanto a una carpeta determinada le puedo dar acceso por FTP por lo cual no habria problema

Comment: Si se puede al usuario le das permiso de lectura, escritura, ejecución, etc.. al esquema que quieres (incluso puedes darle permisos de administrador sobre un esquema. Necesitas ayuda con eso?

Comment: @zercool es un usuario de cPanel a lo que te refieres verdad ?

Comment: No, un usuario del mysql, veo que en la etiqueta de la pregunta tienes phpmyadmin por ello intuyo eso. Si el phpmyadmin es accesible desde internet el puede meterse con un usuario que tu le indiques y ver el esquema al que ese usuario tenga acceso.

Comment: @zerocool yo se como crear un usuario a y asignarlo a una base de datos dandole permisos determinados, pero lo que quiero es que el pueda entrar al PhpMyadmin (Me imagino que tendria que entrar al cPanel primero) para que el pueda manejar su base de datos a su gusto sin que pueda ver las otras 19 base de datos mias, es posible?

Comment: El phpmyadmin puedes hacerlo accesible directamente o deberías poder, tienes que hablar con el soporte de hostgator. Intenta acceder directamente al phpmyadmin sin pasar por el cpanel a ver, si puedes entonces está accesible, dale esa url y listo, claro luego de crearle el usuario y eso.

Comment: Generalmente puedes acceder a PHPMyAdmin por una URL directamente sin tener que pasar por cPanel. En ese caso él podrá ingresar con el usuario que hayas creado y que tendrá permiso para una base de datos específica. También puedes crear un túnel y dar acceso mediante llaves públicas/privadas. La configuración es más complicada pero para trabajar es más cómodo (no tendría que usar PHPMyAdmin obligatoriamente sino cualquier otro cliente -para mi gusto PHPMyAdmin es demasiado lento y en remoto más aún-) y es más seguro.